# Visual Studio Code html formatting doesn't work

Tags: visual-studio-code

Code formatting doesn't seem work in Visual Studio Code. I have tried with `shift+alt+f`, but it wouldn't format html code. I run `ctrl+shift+p` and type Format and only option I have is Format Document(`shift+alt+f`) and Format Selection (don't have Format code). I don't understand what I' doing wrong? Do I need to install some kind of extension in order for this formatting to work on html files?

Comment: Basic HTML formatting should be built in. Are `Format Document` and `Format Selection` not doing anything? If so, please [open an issue against VSCode](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues) (or `Help -> Report Issue` from inside VSCode). Be sure to include an example file, VSCode version, and any installed extensions. Thanks.

Comment: Having the same issue, format selection also doesn't do anything. File has `.html` extension. Switched of eslint as formatter fixed it.

Comment: I can say I don't care for how the standard VS Code HTML formatting works. Indentation is horrible, things indent right but the end tag doesn't indent back, the next line does though. I also wish certain tags where in their own lines. Don't like it. Haven't liked the code formatting in VS since 2010...

Answer (score 24):

This worked for me:

1. Right click inside html file that is being edited.
2. Select "Format Document With...".
3. Selected "Configure Default Formatter ...".
4. Changed from "Prettier - Code formatter" to "HTML Language Features".

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me in Visual Studio 2015 (VS2015):

1. Right-click on the code window with the HTML you want to format
2. Click 'Un-minify" in the popup menu.

That worked for me when Format Document (Ctrl-K, Ctrl-D) and Format Selection (Ctrk-K, Ctrl-F) failed to format HTML that I pasted into a Visual Studio HTML document.

Comment: The OP was talking about Visual Studio Code, not the full featured IDE.

Comment: Yep, missed that...my bad.

Answer (score 3):

There are two scenarios here

1. You are editing an html file with a non-standard html extension. Find fix #1 below.
2. You are editing a non-html file with html embedded. For this scenario find fix #2.

Both fixes involve installing the [Beautify](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HookyQR.beautify) extension so do that first.

**Fix 1**

To fix this issue, you will need to update your js-beautify extension properties to include those types. From the Beautify documentation:

```
You can contol which file types, extensions, or specific file names should 
be beautified with the beautify.language setting.

{
  "beautify.language": {
    "js": {
      "type": ["javascript", "json"],
      "filename": [".jshintrc", ".jsbeautifyrc"]
      // "ext": ["js", "json"]
      // ^^ to set extensions to be beautified using the javascript beautifier
    },
    "css": ["css", "scss"],
    "html": ["htm", "html"]
    // ^^ providing just an array sets the VS Code file type
  }
}
```

**Fix 2**

In this case when you run the beautify command (after installing the extension) it will prompt you for the language type. Select html and voila.

Comment: Also make sure before Fix 2, check what is the HTML file being read as, in my case it was being read as a Django File because of a plugin that I had installed. I disabled the app for the work-space so that I could work in comfort on my Angular App now.

Answer (score 0):

You might have some error in your html document like maybe you forgot to close a tag. I had the same problem but after fixing that error code formatting works well. If you have a large file then try pasting your code here and validating it [here](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input)